# Using ifstream in a class

Tags: c++, class, ifstream

I'm getting the following errors when using ifstream in a .h file and the implementation file,,I have the the fstream include files in both the main ,the method definitions and .h file.

```
'no void Rational::read(std::ifstream&)' member function declared in class  variable or field `read' declared void
```

Heres the method declaration in the rational class .h file.

```
void read(ifstream &);
```

And the method definition.

```
void Rational::read(ifstream &ratfile)
```

Comment: Is ifstream properly qualified with `std::` in the header file?

Comment: no i have the #include <fstream> in the header file, i dont know whether thats proper or not

Comment: ah thanks thats what i was missing

Comment: Do you want to close or delete this question then?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
void read(std::ifstream &); // in the header file

void Rational::read(std::ifstream &ratfile) // in the cpp file